Restoring Poincaré symmetries in Hamiltonian lattice field theories
I can imagine how the continuum limit of a non-relativistic quantum field theory discretized on a spatial lattice restores the Galilean symmetries of the original theory. But how does this work for lattice formulations of relativistic field theories, such as Kogut-Susskind?
Naïvely, it seems that putting a relativistic system on a spatial lattice turns it into a non-relativistic quantum many-body system (potentially with some weird degrees of freedom living on various manifolds, etc.) So is there anything relativistic about this resulting system, besides the dispersion relation of the free discretized model resembling the free dispersion relation of the original theory in some limit?
To put it differently, can I construct operators in the lattice theory which in the continuum limit will approach the Poincaré transformations?


Im not very familiar with hamiltonian formulations but generally, the lattice can be seen as any other regulator. When removing it (taking the continuum limit) one should recover continuum physics, and the right generators of the continuum poincare transformations. In practice, this is done by correctly renormalizing them, i.e. tuning renormalization constants such that continuum ward identities are fulfilled up to discretization effects. Let me know if I have misunderstood your question.
